# Calculating Arithmetic and Geometric mean by introducing numbers until 0 is pressed

Tags: c, scanf

I have to calculate the arithmetic and geometrical mean of numbers entered by the user in C language. The algorithm works fine, but I don't know how to do the *enter numbers until 0 is pressed* part. I have tried many things but nothing works. Here is what I have tried to do until now. Thanks for the help.

```
int main() {
    int n, i, m, j, arr[50], sum = 0, prod = 1;

    printf("Enter numbers until you press number 0:");
    scanf("%d",&n);
    while (n != 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            scanf("%d", &arr[i]);
            sum = sum + arr[i];
            prod = prod * arr[i];
        }
    }
    int armean = sum / n;
    float geomean = pow(prod, (float)1 / n);

    printf("Arithmetic Mean = %d\n", armean);
    printf("Geometric Mean = %f\n", geomean);
    getch();
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Your code is asking for the number of values in advance and subsequently reading that many values.  That's not what you were asked to do.

You need to ask for numbers in a loop and exit the loop when the number that you read is 0.  You don't even need an array:

```
int n = 0, i, m, j, sum=0, prod=1;

while (1) {
    int value;
    scanf("%d",&value);
    if (value == 0) {
        break;
    }

    sum=sum+value;
    prod=prod*value;
    n++;
}

int armean=sum/n;
float geomean=pow(prod,(float) 1/n);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. You have to break the for loop when value 0 entered; so you should check for arr[i].
2. While loop is not required.

Please go through below code; this could be help full:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{

    int n, i, m, j, arr[50], sum=0, prod=1;
    printf("Enter numbers until you press number 0:");
    for(i=0; i<50; i++)
    {
        scanf("%d",&arr[i]);
        if (arr[i] == 0)
        {
            break;
        }
        sum=sum+arr[i];
        prod=prod*arr[i];
    }
    printf ("%d %d\n",sum, prod);
    n = i+1;
    int armean=sum/n;
    float geomean=pow(prod,(float) 1/n);

    printf("Arithmetic Mean = %d\n",armean);
    printf("Geometric Mean = %f\n",geomean);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

what dbush said is right, you don't need array and are not asking the number in advance but what he did not tell is how can you find the number of values

```
int main()
{
int n, sum=0, prod=1, num;
printf("Enter numbers until you press number 0:\n");
for(n=0; ; n++)
{
    scanf("%d",&num);
    if(num==0)
        break;

    sum=sum+num;
    prod=prod*num;
}
printf("sum is %d \n",sum);
printf("prod is %d \n",prod);
printf("n is %d \n",n);
float armean=sum/n; //why int?
float geomean=pow(prod,(float) 1/n);

printf("Arithmetic Mean = %d\n",armean);
printf("Geometric Mean = %f\n",geomean);
//getch();  why getch(), you are not using turboc are you?
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for an array, but you should test if the number entered in `0` after reading it from the user. It would be better also to use floating point arithmetic to avoid arithmetic overflow, which would occur quickly on the product of values.

In any case, you must include `<math.h>` for `pow` to be correctly defined, you should test the return value of `scanf()` and avoid dividing by `0` if no numbers were entered before `0`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main() {
    int n = 0;
    double value, sum = 0, product = 1;
    printf("Enter numbers, end with 0: ");
    while (scanf("%lf", &value) == 1 && value != 0) {
        sum += value;
        product *= value;
        n++;
    }
    if (n > 0) {
        printf("Arithmetic mean = %g\n", sum / n);
        printf("Geometric mean = %g\n", pow(product, 1.0 / n));
        getch();
    }
    return 0;
}
```